# download image from api response and api response is not the url , it is image code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, asp.net, angularjs

I am using this code to get the image download. please suggest me what code I need to add to download the image from API response in angular js.

```
var lang = locale.getLocale();
var token = AuthToken.get();
Restangular.one("wallpaper").customGET
(undefined, {
    'X-Authorization':'Bearer ' + token,
    'Accept-Language':lang,
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',                           
    'accept':'image/jpeg'
})
.then(function(res){  

    scope.image=res;
    modalInstance = $modal.open(opts);
    $rootScope.reqLoading = false;
});
```

Comment: You can create a link with `_blank` property that would hit the url on a server which would contain the download functionality.

Comment: What you are getting in 'res' . Is res is image url?

Comment: no, it is not image url, it is returning code like

����JFIF��;CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), quality = 90 ��C   

��C  

���8"�� ���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������� ���w!1AQaq"2�B����

Answer (score 1):

you can utilize the below code-

```
// download via the download attribute
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.download = 'test.png';
a.href = 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQcWzAJb0c3t1waqim9j4-vBqXWHXcgjzV8FRARcxTOp8wxtvBc';
a.click();
```

```js
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.download = 'test.png';
a.href = 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQcWzAJb0c3t1waqim9j4-vBqXWHXcgjzV8FRARcxTOp8wxtvBc';
a.click();
```

Comment: I don't have image url, i am getting code from api not url, i need to download that code as image.